# Linear ODE Cauchy problem: issue in the distributional solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, cauchy-problem

I am considering the following Initial Value problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&u'+\alpha u = \cos \omega t\\
& u(0)=u_0
\end{aligned}
$$
The solution is:
$$u(t) ={\rm e}^{-\alpha t} \left(u_0-{\frac {
\alpha}{{\alpha}^{2}+{\omega}^{2}}} \right)+\frac {\alpha\cos\omega t+\omega\sin\omega t}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}
$$
I now want to solve the equation using a distribution of the form $U(t)=H(t)u(t)$ where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside distribution. Since $U'=u'+u_0\delta$, we have to solve
$$U'+\alpha U=\cos \omega t + u_0\delta$$
in the sense of distributions, which means, using classical convolution formulation
$$(\delta'+\alpha\delta)*U=\cos\omega t + u_0\delta$$
The convolution inverse of $\delta'+\alpha\delta$ is $G(t)=H(t)\exp(-\alpha t)$ and so, if I am correct, the sought solution is $U(t)=G(t)*(\cos\omega t+u_0\delta)$ that is:
$$U(t)=H(t)\Bigl[u_0\exp(-\alpha t)+\frac{\alpha\cos \omega t +\alpha\sin\omega t}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}\Bigr]$$
Obviously there is something wrong in the derivations above, since the two solutions do not match. I cannot find where.

**Solution**

Based on md2perpe's comments and reply, below is a detailed solution. From $U'+\alpha U=H(t)\cos \omega t + u_0\delta$, we can say that
$$U(t)=G(t)*(H(t)\cos\omega t+u_0\delta)$$
where $G(t)=H(t)\exp(-\alpha t)$. Expanding the convolution yields: 
$$U(t)=\int_0^{t}{\rm e}^{-\alpha s}\cos\omega (t-s)\mathrm{d}s+u_0{\rm e}^{-\alpha t}$$
that is
$$U(t)=H(t)\Bigl({\rm e}^{-\alpha t} \left(u_0-{\frac {
\alpha}{{\alpha}^{2}+{\omega}^{2}}} \right)+\frac {\alpha\cos\omega t+\omega\sin\omega t}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}\Bigr)$$
as expected.

Comment: Without having deep-dived, one question hits me: can there really exist a solution that vanishes for $t<0$ but not for $t>0$?

Comment: @md2perpe We assume that the solution vanishes for negative $t$, or more exactly, we do not really care about what happens for negative $t$, so we have a look at a distributional solution in the $\mathcal D'_+$ algebra...

Comment: There is an important difference between "assume that the solution vanishes for negative $t$" and "do not really care about what happens for negative $t$". The first one forces the solution to be zero for negative $t$ which might result in $u'$ having a $\delta(t)$-term. The second does not.

Comment: If you want to force $u(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and solve it using distributions, try to change the problem to
$$
u'(t) + \alpha u(t) = \cos\omega t \, H(t) + c \, \delta(t),
\quad
u(0) = u_0.
$$

Comment: @md2perpe you are right, I thought about the difference right after my comment and we should assume that $u$ vanishes for negative $t$. What I can say is that the approach described in my post works well without the $\cos \omega t$ term. Things go differently with it and the initial condition seems to be a problem. I will think about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions to $u' + \alpha u = \cos \omega t$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$ have the form
$$u(t) = A \cos \omega t + B \sin \omega t + C e^{-\alpha t}.$$

Let $v(t) = u(t)$ for $t>0$ and $v(t) \equiv 0$ for $t<0$. This can be written
$v(t) = u(t) \, H(t).$

What happens when we insert this into the differential equation, treating $v$ as a distribution? We have
$$v'(t) = u'(t) \, H(t) + u(t) \, H'(t) = u'(t) \, H(t) + u(0) \, \delta(t)$$
giving
$$\begin{align}
v'(t) + \alpha v(t) 
&= \left( u'(t) \, H(t) + u(0) \, \delta(t) \right) + \alpha \left( u(t) \, H(t) \right) \\
&= \left( u'(t) + \alpha u(t) \right) H(t) + u(0) \, \delta(t) \\
&= \cos \omega t \, H(t) + u(0) \, \delta(t).
\end{align}$$
We can see here that you have missed the factor $H(t)$ after $\cos \omega t$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about the missing $H(t)$ but if we follow the convolution procedure, the $H(t)$ in "my" $G(t)$ above will simplify, I think, with the $H(t)$ in $\cos\omega t H(t)$ so I am not whether it makes a difference?

Comment: How do you mean that it will simplify?

Comment: Your solution should be
$$U(t)=G(t)*(\cos\omega t \, H(t) + u_0\delta).$$
Do you mean that the $H(t)$ in $G(t)$ and the $H(t)$ in the parenthesis should multiply to form $H(t)$?

Comment: yes! I see that it becomes $H(t)H(s-t)$ in the convolution. I have to compute it.

Comment: $H*H = t H$ but you also have the factor $e^{-\alpha t}$ which complicates matter a bit.

Comment: yes, I just checked and it works with the $H(t)\cos\omega t$!